# Visual Studio 2012 loading error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, load

I have an error when I load Visual Studio 2012: "An exception has been encountered. This may be caused by an extension."

And here is the message from the xml file:

```
System.ComponentModel.Composition.CompositionException: The composition produced a single composition error, with 2 root causes. 
The root causes are provided below. 
Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information.
) The export Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.SVsServiceProvider is not assignable to type System.Boolean.

Resulting in: Cannot set import &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Shared.IRegistryManager.IsKnockoutEnabled (ContractName=&quot;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.SVsServiceProvider&quot;)&apos; on part &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Shared.RegistryManager&apos;.
Element: Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Shared.IRegistryManager.IsKnockoutEnabled (ContractName=&quot;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.SVsServiceProvider&quot;) --&gt;  Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Shared.RegistryManager

Resulting in: Cannot get export &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Shared.RegistryManager (ContractName=&quot;Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Shared.IRegistryManager&quot;)&apos; from part &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Shared.RegistryManager&apos;.
Element: Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Shared.RegistryManager (ContractName=&quot;Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Shared.IRegistryManager&quot;) --&gt;  Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Shared.RegistryManager

Resulting in: Cannot set import &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Shared.IBufferFeatureManagerProvider.teBufferFeatureManager (ContractName=&quot;Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Shared.IRegistryManager&quot;)&apos; on part &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Shared.BufferFeatureManagerProvider&apos;.
Element: Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Shared.IBufferFeatureManagerProvider.teBufferFeatureManager (ContractName=&quot;Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Shared.IRegistryManager&quot;) --&gt;  Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Shared.BufferFeatureManagerProvider

Resulting in: Cannot get export &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Shared.BufferFeatureManagerProvider (ContractName=&quot;Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Shared.IBufferFeatureManagerProvider&quot;)&apos; from part &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Shared.BufferFeatureManagerProvider&apos;.
Element: Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Shared.BufferFeatureManagerProvider (ContractName=&quot;Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Shared.IBufferFeatureManagerProvider&quot;) --&gt;  Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Shared.BufferFeatureManagerProvider

Resulting in: Cannot set import &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Classification.SPARegionTaggerProvider.BufferFeatureManagerProvider (ContractName=&quot;Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Shared.IBufferFeatureManagerProvider&quot;)&apos; on part &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Classification.SPARegionTaggerProvider&apos;.
Element: Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Classification.SPARegionTaggerProvider.BufferFeatureManagerProvider (ContractName=&quot;Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Shared.IBufferFeatureManagerProvider&quot;) --&gt;  Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Classification.SPARegionTaggerProvider

Resulting in: Cannot get export &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Classification.SPARegionTaggerProvider (ContractName=&quot;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Tagging.IViewTaggerProvider&quot;)&apos; from part &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Classification.SPARegionTaggerProvider&apos;.
Element: Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Classification.SPARegionTaggerProvider (ContractName=&quot;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Tagging.IViewTaggerProvider&quot;) --&gt;  Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Classification.SPARegionTaggerProvider

2) The export &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Extensions.HTML.TagNameProvider (ContractName=&quot;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Extensions.HTML.ITagNameProvider&quot;)&apos; is not assignable to type &apos;System.Collections.Generic.ISet`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]&apos;.

Resulting in: Cannot set import &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Shared.ISPASupportedTagProvider.SupportedTagNames (ContractName=&quot;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Extensions.HTML.ITagNameProvider&quot;)&apos; on part &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Shared.SPASupportedTagSet&apos;.
Element: Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Shared.ISPASupportedTagProvider.SupportedTagNames (ContractName=&quot;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Extensions.HTML.ITagNameProvider&quot;) --&gt;  Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Shared.SPASupportedTagSet

Resulting in: Cannot get export &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Shared.SPASupportedTagSet (ContractName=&quot;Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Shared.ISPASupportedTagProvider&quot;)&apos; from part &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Shared.SPASupportedTagSet&apos;.
Element: Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Shared.SPASupportedTagSet (ContractName=&quot;Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Shared.ISPASupportedTagProvider&quot;) --&gt;  Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Shared.SPASupportedTagSet

Resulting in: Cannot set import &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Classification.SPARegionTaggerProvider.TagNameProvider (ContractName=&quot;Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Shared.ISPASupportedTagProvider&quot;)&apos; on part &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Classification.SPARegionTaggerProvider&apos;.
Element: Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Classification.SPARegionTaggerProvider.TagNameProvider (ContractName=&quot;Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Shared.ISPASupportedTagProvider&quot;) --&gt;  Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Classification.SPARegionTaggerProvider

Resulting in: Cannot get export &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Classification.SPARegionTaggerProvider (ContractName=&quot;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Tagging.IViewTaggerProvider&quot;)&apos; from part &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Classification.SPARegionTaggerProvider&apos;.
Element: Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Classification.SPARegionTaggerProvider (ContractName=&quot;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Tagging.IViewTaggerProvider&quot;) --&gt;  Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Web.Extensions.Classification.SPARegionTaggerProvider

   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CompositionServices.GetExportedValueFromComposedPart(ImportEngine engine, ComposablePart part, ExportDefinition definition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider.GetExportedValue(CatalogPart part, ExportDefinition export, Boolean isSharedPart)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider.CatalogExport.GetExportedValueCore()
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.Export.get_Value()
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportServices.GetCastedExportedValue[T](Export export)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportServices.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass4`2.&lt;CreateStronglyTypedLazyOfTM&gt;b__1()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Tagging.Implementation.TagAggregator`1.GatherTaggers(ITextBuffer textBuffer)</description>
```

Does anybody know I can fix it?

Regards,

Benjamin

Comment: What extensions have you installed?

Answer (score 1):

Cool, this is what worked for me, update the assemblies tag in the web.config file. During the load of the project the IDE is not able to load those assemblies. So here is my below...

```
          <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  <add assembly="System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  <add assembly="System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
  <add assembly="System.Web.ApplicationServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  <add assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
  <add assembly="System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
  <add assembly="System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
  <add assembly="System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
  <add assembly="System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
  <add assembly="System.Web.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
  <add assembly="System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
  <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
  <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
  <add assembly="System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
  <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
  <add assembly="System.ServiceModel.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  <add assembly="System.Data.Services.Client, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
  <add assembly="System.Data.Services.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
  <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
  <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
  <add assembly="System.Web.DynamicData, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  <add assembly="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  <add assembly="System.Web.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
  <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
```

Comment: If it still persisting, try updating some of your plugins especially Web Essentials plugin..

Comment: Yep - i had similar error to the OP, with "2 root causes" - though different stack traces, and updating Web Essentials fixed the problem.